# Metric to compare conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, symmetry, equivalent-metrics

I am working on a machine translation task and there are two kind of probabilities:

- $p_1 = Pr(\epsilon | \phi)$
- $p_2 = Pr(\phi | \epsilon)$

Where $\epsilon$ and $\phi$ are phrases in source and target languages.

Sometimes this probabilities become hugely different. One of the possible reasons: system made a mistake and issued trashy translation which is better to be discarded.

I would like to construct a metric that equals to $0$ if $p_1 = p_2$ and approaches $1$ the more $p_1$ and $p_2$ are different. It also would be nice to have a hyperparameter to tune how fast it goes towards $1$.

Please help.

Comment: Isn't $d(p_1,p_2)=0$ in the case of $p_1=p_2$ for any metric, by definition?

Comment: @Botond Sure, patched it up.

Comment: You could try total variation distance, or the close relative, KL-Divergence. KL-Divergence is not a metric (it's not even symmetric) but I know it is commonly used for this sort of stuff... Just from a theory standpoint, it seems that these two conditional probabilities should regularly diverge quite a bit. for example, if $\epsilon$ is the phrase "and" and $\phi$ is the phrase "the" then $\Pr(\epsilon | \phi)$ should be small, but $\Pr(\phi | \epsilon)$ should be large.

Comment: @mm8511 Thanks for KLD, using it heavily in particular machine learning problems, will try it out in this task. As for your comment — there is plenty of room for experiment (as always when it comes to implementation), but the main goal is to be able to rank different translations and not to rely on frequencies which are deceptive when it comes to common words.